# Can't draw rectangles on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, paint

I'm currently trying to learn more about painting in swing and I'm creating a little game but I seem to be stuck. I'm trying to add a couple rectangles (Enemies) to an ArrayList then draw them in the `paintComponent()` method but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Enemy class

```
import utils.RandomUtils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Enemy
{
    double x, y, w, h;
    Shape enemy;

    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    double width = tk.getScreenSize().width;
    double height = tk.getScreenSize().height;

    RandomUtils utils = new RandomUtils();

    public Enemy(int w, int h)
    {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;

        enemy = new Rectangle2D.Double(setX(), setY(), w, h);
    }

    private double setX()
    {
        return x = utils.randInt((int) w, (int) width);
    }

    private double setY()
    {
        return y = utils.randInt((int) h, (int) height);
    }

    public Shape getEnemy()
    {
        return enemy;
    }
}
```

Here is my Board class

```
import players.Enemy;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Board extends JPanel
{
    int x, y, speed = 1, height = 25, width = 25;

    public Board()
    {
        addControls();
    }

    public void addControls()
    {
        Action upAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                y = y - speed;
                repaint();
            }
        };

        getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "Up Action");
        getActionMap().put("Up Action", upAction);

        Action downAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                y = y + speed;
                repaint();
            }
        };

        getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "Down Action");
        getActionMap().put("Down Action", downAction);

        Action leftAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                x = x - speed;
                repaint();
            }
        };

        getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "Left Action");
        getActionMap().put("Left Action", leftAction);

        Action rightAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                x = x + speed;
                repaint();
            }
        };

        getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "Right Action");
        getActionMap().put("Right Action", rightAction);
    }

    boolean enemiesDrawn = false;
    java.util.List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
    java.util.List<Shape> enemyShapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setEnemies()
    {
        for(int enemyCount = 0; enemyCount < 15; enemyCount++)
        {
            System.out.println(enemyCount);
            enemies.add(new Enemy(15, 15));
            enemyShapes.add(enemies.get(enemyCount).getEnemy());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);

        if(!enemiesDrawn)
        {
            setEnemies();

            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            enemyShapes.forEach(g2::draw);

            enemiesDrawn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Util class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomUtils
{
    public RandomUtils()
    {
    }

    public int randInt(int min, int max)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

And main class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame
{
    JFrame mainFrame;

    public MainFrame()
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Game");

        addComponents();

        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addComponents()
    {
        mainFrame.add(new Board());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainFrame::new);
    }
}
```

Painting the Oval (player) works just fine, I just can't seem to draw the enemies in the List. What should/could I do to fix this?

Comment: What's the point of having two ArrayLists? Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: One for the enemies themselves and one for the shapes of the enemies. I'll post the full code.

Comment: Side recommendation, never dispose of a Graphics object, `g2.dispose();`, given to you by the JVM. Only dispose of the ones you yourself create such as from images or from other Graphics objects. Doing this risks breaking the painting chain.

Comment: Yeah, but all you're doing is adding the shape defined by `Enemy` to another array, seems like a significant area for problems if the two lists by unsynchornised

Comment: `RandomUtils` should create a single instance of `Random`, you're running the risk of it return the same sequence of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your main problem is here...

```
if (!enemiesDrawn) {
    setEnemies();

    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    System.out.println("...");
    enemyShapes.forEach(g2::draw);

    enemiesDrawn = true;
}
```

Once `paintComponent` is called once, the enemies will never be painted again. `paintComponent` may be called lots of times (often in quick succession), each time it's called, you are expected to repaint the entire state of the component again, from scratch.

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

**Observations**...

This is kind of pointless...

```
mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
mainFrame.pack();
```

You're setting the frame maximized but then trying to pack it?  This could cause issues on some systems, so beware.

`RandomUtils` should create a single instance of `Random`, because of the way it works, you're running the risk of having `Random` return the same values, in the same order. You could just about get away with a singleton

```
public enum RandomUtils {

    INSTANCE;

    private Random rand = new Random();

    public int randInt(int min, int max) {
        return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Using `Toolkit` in your `Enemy` is not a good idea, apart from the fact that the enemy should have little knowledge of the outside world, `Toolkit` isn't the best choice for determining the actual viewable screen size, given the fact that your window has decorations and the desktop has things like taskbars, this is running the risk that some of your enemies will appear of screen

Because of the way your program works, it's kind of hard to suggestion something that would replicate the output.  But basically, you should be passing the desired location/size to the constructor of the `Enemy` class.

You could use a `ComponentListener` and monitor the `componentResized` method, which it first stabilizes, you could then create the enemies based on the current size of the component

Comment: Ahhh, I see! Thanks for the answer. It's now fully working.